# Autofill Column using data from a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with one column that must be filled, evenly, with names every morning. Historically, Excel's autofill function has been able to fulfill that need but as usage of this sheet is being expanded to other users, I am looking to make this step fault-proof. What I would like to have happen is for the column E (500+ empty rows) in table 2 to be filled with the data from column A (approx. 15 names) in table 1, in sequential order.

```
Sub TableTransfer()

Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As Long

Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
TempArray = myTable.DataBodyRange
myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

Set otherTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")
Range(otherTable) = myArray

For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
Next x

End Sub
```

The code above is only using the first table row in table 1, but I need it to loop through all the table rows in table 1 and transfer them to all the empty rows in table2.